# How to redirect to route when all routes are loaded dynamically based on condition?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my code to load routes (react router dom 5) based on user object in context.

```
function App() {
  return (
      <UserContextProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navigation/>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </UserContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Navigation code. Here I conditionally load routes.

```
function Navigation() {

  const { contextState } = useUserContext();

  const routes = contextState.user ? routesAuthenticated : routerUnauthenticated;
  
  return (
    <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, index) => {
            return (
                <Route
                    key={index}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    render={(props: RouteComponentProps) => (
                        <route.component name={route.name} {...props} {...route.props} />
                    )}
                />
            );
        })}
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

You see that based on context user object I load different routes.
Routes are simple config files:

```
export const routerUnauthenticated: IRoute[] = [
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Register page',
    component: RegisterPage,
    exact: false,
  },
  {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login page',
      component: LoginPage,
      exact: false,
  }...
```

Problem is I am on route `http://localhost:3000/login` and after succesfull login I got blank page with route `http://localhost:3000/login`.
Before login I have 3 routes login/register/home.
After login I have 5 routes dashboard/profile...
What I am trying to do is after successfull login get to `/dashboard` route but because of my idea with dynamic routes loading I can't figure how to navigate.

Login is simple fake function in my context:

```
try {
        setContextState({ type: ContextActions.LOGIN_IN_PROGRESS });

        setTimeout(() => {console.log({ userId: 1, username: 'admin@admin.com' });
          setContextState({ type: ContextActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: { user: { userId: 1, username: 'admin@admin.com' } } });
        }, 3000);
      } catch(error) {
        setContextState({ type: ContextActions.LOGIN_ERROR });
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just load all the routes?
You can use a custom Route component to see if the **contextState.user** exists
Kind of like a protected route which redirects to /login or /register if a non authenticated user goes to that route.

Comment: This question need proper answer this kind of query or explanation can be given in the comments

Comment: Actually in the end I solved it this way. Thanks for idea on protected routes.

Comment: @1110 Added a common `protectedRoute` component, check if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common protectedRoute component that is being used widely.

```html
const App = () => {
    const { user } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/public">
          <Public />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path='/protected' user={user}>
          <Protected />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, user, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={({ location }) => {
      return user === null
        ? <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: location }
          }}
        />
        : children
    }} />
)
```